# LocalDateTime comparison with negative date time

Tags: java, java-time, compareto, localdatetime

I have an issue on checking future date at the server. Since Date.parse() parse differently under  chrome and Firefox. Under Firefox, a negative date time is passed to the server. Since I want to avoid this kind of browser problem, I tried to implement a validation on server side.

```java
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date interviewingDate = interview.getInterviewingDate();
LocalDateTime currentDateTime = convertToLocalDateTime(currentDate);
LocalDateTime interviewingDateTime = convertToLocalDateTime(interview.getInterviewingDate());
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedCurrentDateTime = currentDateTime.format(formatter);
String formattedInterviewDateTime = interviewingDateTime.format(formatter);
```

I tried to compare the server time with the case interviewing time. Since the future day is not allowed, `if(interviewingDateTime.isAfter(currentDateTime)) return -1`

But when I test it, the result is not I expected.

Here's some log:
currentDateTime.getTime() 1607592350160
interviewingDateTime.getTime() -125883137443000

formattedCurrentDateTime 2020-12-10 17:25:50 
formattedInterviewDateTime 2021-12-03 13:55:00

currentDateTime toLocalDate 2020-12-10
interviewingDateTime toLocalDate -2020-12-03
interviewingDateTime.toLocalTime()13:55
currentDateTime.toLocalTime() 17:25:50.160

interviewingDateTime.isAfter(currentDateTime): false
interviewingDate.compareTo(currentDate): -1

I expect isAfter returns true since interviewing time is a future date.
And I see there's negative value when I tried to output the local date and the original Date object getTime(). Is there anyway to convert the negative to back to normal positive date ? Or any other way to compare and check the date is future date as expected ?

Comment: We don't know how `interviewingDate` is being derived. The value you've given is in 1966, which seems unlikely to be correct. I would start there - nothing after that matters until you've got the right value there. I would really, really try to avoid using `java.util.Date` at all though.

Comment: Separately, you're talking about `Date.parse()` and Chrome vs Firefox - but that's Javascript code, not Java. I strongly suspect you should avoid parsing the date in the browser at all - just send an ISO-8601 text representation and parse it server-side.

Comment: I am using hibernate mapping the date, so the front end is passing the date value as  -125883137443000. But why the formatted string date is correct?

Comment: I can't tell, because you haven't shown `convertToLocalDateTime`. This is where a [mcve] would make it a lot easier to help you. But unless the value is *really* meant to represent a date in 1966, the first thing you need to fix is the frontend, possibly changing it to pass a textual representation instead of a number. (We don't know where the information is coming from - is this user input?) There's so much we don't know here, it's hard to help you.

Comment: -125883137443000 milliseoncds (so 125 883 137 443 seconds *before* the epoch) is in year 2021 BCE alright. Before the common era, “before Christ”. How you got that value I can’t tell.

Comment: @JonSkeet Year 1966 assumes the number denotes microseconds. I believe they are milliseconds.

Comment: @OleV.V.: Whoops, you're right. I misread epochconverter.com.

Answer (score 1):

Check your variable Date interviewDate before the conversion. if it's not a problem, Probally the issue is on method 'convertToLocalDateTime'. Try the simple code below.

```
public static LocalDateTime convertToLocalDateTime(Date date) {
    return date.toInstant()
               .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
               .toLocalDateTime();  
}
```